# Map typescript parameter: Binding element 'contacts' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this code taken from a JavaScript post and I would like to use it in typescript but I get an error in: `const Contacts = ({contacts}) => {`

I tried `{contacts: []}` without success.
Contacts is located in App states.

```js
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Contacts from './components/contacts';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    contacts: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ contacts: data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Contacts contacts={this.state.contacts} />
    )
  }
}
export default App;


***contact.tsx ***
import React from 'react'
    
    const Contacts = ({contacts}) => {Binding element 'contacts' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Contact List</h1>
          {contacts.map((contact: any) => (
            <div>
              <div>
                <h5>{contact.name}</h5>
                <h6>{contact.email}</h6>
                <p>{contact.company.catchPhrase}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )
    };

    export default Contacts
```

I get the error:

> Binding element 'contacts' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)

Comment: `const Contacts = ({contacts}: {contacts: any})`, but it's better not to use any or disable `noImplicitAny`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell ts what the props of Contacts are. You should write an interface like this:

```
interface ContactProps {
     contacts: any[];
}
```

And set this interface to the Contacts component like this:

```
 const Contacts: FC<ContactProps> = ({contacts}) => {...}
```

or

```
 const Contacts = ({contacts}: ContactProps) => {...}
```

This will infer the type of the props you pass to Contacts and will remove that error. You should also define the interface contact and write it like this:

```
interface Contact {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    ....
}
interface ContactProps {
     contacts: Contact[];
}
```

This will now let you work with correct types and will remove the any, which is currently present. This will also help you catch errors like typos and what to pass to the child components.
Hope this helps.
Happy coding.

Comment: @giopoi your solution is perfect!!! React typescript example are rare so I lose a lot of time

Comment: If you have any more questions, hit me up.

Answer (score 2):

```js
//it's ugly but it works
import React from 'react'

    const Contacts = ({contacts}:any) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Contact List</h1>
          {contacts.map((contact: any) => (
            <div>
              <div>
                <h5>{contact.name}</h5>
                <h6>{contact.email}</h6>
                <p>{contact.company.catchPhrase}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )
    };

    export default Contacts
```