# Gatsby Link passing Props error accessing prop on destination page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby, react-typescript

I am attempting to pass a value to another page to do conditional rendering but I am getting a bug where I cannot build the page because location is underfined it seems. I have looked everywhere and cannot work this out anything you can advise will be greatly apperciated.

Original Page (works fine):

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const ProfilePayment = ({     
  return (              
<Link
   to={`/pay-on-line${search ? `?c=${search}` : ''}`}
   state={{ myProp: agentID }}>
)
})

export default ProfilePayment
```

Pay-on-line page - produces error Property 'state' does not exist on type 'Location':

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout/layout'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNumbers } from '../components/NumbersProvider/NumbersProvider'
import { useQueryParam } from '../hooks/useQueryParam'

const PayOnline = () => {
return (
{console.log(location.state.myProp)}
)

export default PayOnline
```

Answer (score 2):

This is attempting to access `window.location.state.myProp`. Since `location` is not in the global scope during SSR and `window` is not available, you might be running into issues with `location` being `undefined`.

Either way, the `location` you're referring to here (`window.location`) probably does not have a `state` property, which means that accessing `myProp` on it will throw an error as you are trying to access a property of `undefined`.

```
{console.log(location.state.myProp)}
```

You probably instead want to follow [this example](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/), destructuring the `location` prop and accessing the `state` prop on it:

```
const Photo = ({ location, photoId }) => {
  if (location.state.fromFeed) {
    return <FromFeedPhoto id={photoId} />
  } else {
    return <Photo id={photoId} />
  }
}
```

Comment: Attempted this and got the error: binding element 'location' implicitly has an 'any' type.  Do i need to export the location from page 1?

Comment: That sounds like a TypeScript type is missing or being misinterpreted. I don't use TypeScript with Gatsby so I can't really help you with that.

Comment: Ahh yes it is type script. Thank you any way will investigate further

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Answering for anyone in the future that gets stuck on a similar issue with Gatsby, Typescript and not being able to use location.state when passing props between pages.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout/layout'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNumbers } from '../components/NumbersProvider/NumbersProvider'
import { useQueryParam } from '../hooks/useQueryParam'

const PayOnline = ( { myProp }: any) => {
const agentProp = myProp
return (
{console.log(agentProp)}
)

export default PayOnline
```

Original article that helped me:
[Map typescript parameter: Binding element 'contacts' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325914/map-typescript-parameter-binding-element-contacts-implicitly-has-an-any-typ)